# timescaledb compression and relations on multiple segment

Tags: postgresql, database-design, timescaledb

I'm currently trying to store a "blockchain" like into TimescaleDB and wanted to leverage the power of compression but without losing the performance on relational queries.

Given this simple schema with millions of blocks and billions of transactions:

```
blocks
-------------------------
block_number    bigint
created_at      timestamp



transactions
-------------------------
hash            text
block_number    bigint
from            text
to              text
created_at      timestamp
```

Creating hypertables with this design and adding compression on the `transactions` table gives me terrible performance when I want to query for instance:

```sql
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE transactions.from = lower('xxxx') AND transactions.to = lower('xxxx');
```

From what I understand, this is expected because data is having index on `created_at` and `segmentby` cannot help me there's because it's a "two-dimension" with "incoming transactions" and "outgoing transactions".

Because compression is really effective with TimescaleDB it should not bother to duplicate the data, am I right?

I was thinking if a database design like this could give me good performance and compression:

```
blocks
-------------------------
block_number    bigint
created_at      timestamp



transactions
-------------------------
hash            text
block_number    bigint
from            text
to              text
created_at      timestamp



incoming_transactions
-------------------------
hash            text
account         text
created_at      timestamp



outgoing_transactions
-------------------------
hash            text
account         text
created_at      timestamp
```

If I compress and segmentby `account` the `outgoing_transactions` and `incoming_transactions` would this query be efficient:

```sql
SELECT 
  transactions.* 
FROM 
  transactions
  INNER JOIN outgoing_transactions ON 
    incoming_transactions.hash = transactions.hash AND account = lower('xxx')
  INNER JOIN outgoing_transactions ON 
    outgoing_transactions.hash = transactions.hash AND account = lower('xxx')
```

Or am I completely wrong and should stick with indices on `transactions.from` and `transactions.to` and without compression?

Thank you

Comment: I think you can benchmark to proof it. But in long term, looks like indices are the best option.

You can also think about have a dimension based on the direction but decomposing this will have a higher cost. One thing that you should try is to optimize the account switching to some more performant data type like UUID or bigint.